# TextView text size and other properties

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

so I was developing an app with Android Studio and I added a 'textview' box in the screen. However, when I tested the app on my device, the text was too small to read. So I tried searching on the web about how to change the text size, but I could only find videos and posts about how to change the font of the android studio product itself. Please tell me how to change the text size in the textview box. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Probably your AS preview size is different from the kind of screen your phone is supporting so you are having that expectation. Remember also that in Android you need to provide a different design for each density if you want to make your app responsive.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can add the following property in the text view's xml and start increasing the number till you reach the font-size you want

```
android:textSize="20sp"
```

The `sp` here inherits the font size the user sets in his/her android device so the same font size may vary on two identical devices